# What is an efficient way to Access class resides in an inventory module from an app module?

Tags: android, oop, module, shared-libraries, android-architecture-components

I need to understand the recommended way to access class in different module.

I have multi-module android project. Where I need to access repository class in Inventory module from the ViewModel class that resides in an App module. is it a good practice? if yes What are the recommended steps to make the communication possible?

Comment: You could use **java reflection API** to load your desired class if having fully-qualified class name.

Comment: @JeelVankhede could you please elaborate, how to do it

Comment: Something like `Class.forName("your complete class with package name")` will give you Class object then you can create object using getting constructor from it and then making it object.